Algebraic structures on spaces of ultrafilters
The space of ultrafilters on $\omega$ has a natural semigroup structure, and ultrafilters that are idempotent in that algebra have seen applications in combinatorics on the natural numbers, for example Hindman's Theorem and Van der Waarden's Theorem on arithmetic progressions.
Are there any interesting analogous structures on spaces of ultrafilters over larger sets, such as uncountable regular cardinals?  At first pass, directly generalizing the semigroup structure and the notion of idempotence seems less interesting.  Suppose we use the semigroup of ordinal addition.  Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal and define the sum $U + W$ of two ultrafilters on $\kappa$ in the analogous way:

$A \in U+W \leftrightarrow \{ \alpha : \{ \alpha+\beta : \beta \in A \} \in U \} \in W \}$.

If $U$ is uniform and concentrates on the set $I$ of indecomposible ordinals, then for all $\alpha<\kappa$, $\{ \alpha+\beta : \beta \in I \} = I \setminus (\alpha +1)$, so every such $U$ satisfies $U+U = U$.
So my vague question is whether there are other natural algebraic structures on ultrafilters on cardinals $\kappa$ (or maybe other sets) where the existence of ultrafilters satisfying certain algebraic properties is rare, useful, or interesting.

There is of course also a natural product structure on the ultrafilters.

If you look at the "natural addition" on ordinals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations), then you can prove a version of van der Waerden's Theorem for any cardinal, or in fact any indecomposable ordinal. And you can prove it by copying over the ultrafilters-based proof for $\omega$, making the appropriate changes. But I'm not sure this is really in the spirit of your question . . . to me, it feels like it has little to do with ordinals or cardinals at all. It's more a theorem about arbitrary commutative semigroups (known as the Gallai Theorem).
